# how to register on available networks in android programmatically?

Tags: android

I want check for the available networks on phone and register on a specific network. Can anybody help me?

I tried following code.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS), 0);
```

and other code too.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
```

it is not solving my problem.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you execute this code, and error(s) are you getting instead? Consider including the error log as part of your question as well.